# using google maps javascript api to plot a the path taken using coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Working with a police department that has a network of License Plate Recognition cameras set up to record the plate image and plate info to a MySQL database for a limited time.  If an Amber Alert (child abduction) is triggered they would like to be able to query the database and get a list of what cameras spotted the plate and then plot those cameras showing the route on a google map.  I have the latitude and longitude of each camera and can generate a map, but it only shows the cameras not the route taken.

I have a script that will pull the data from the database and create an array for the java script to use.  For now to test I have just added the array to the script.  I have been trying everything I can think of from way-points (which is what I think I need) to driving directions and cannot find a good example for plotting points on a route using the coordinates of a camera in an intersection.   Here is what I have so far:

[image: MyGoogleMap]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My Google Map</title>
  <style>
    #map{
      height:500px;
      width:750px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Google Map</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    function initMap(){
      // Map options
      var options = {
        zoom:12,
        center:{lat:40.355048,lng:-79.835499}
      }

      // New map
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

      // Listen for click on map
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
        // Add marker
        addMarker({coords:event.latLng});
      });

      // Array of markers
      var markers = [
        {
        coords:{lat:40.337629,lng:-79.808826},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelW.png',
        content:'<h1>LINCOLN WAY WEST @ 48 2017/12/22 17:49</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.337385,lng:-79.809023},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelS.png',
        content:'<h1>48 SOUTH @ LINCOLN WAY 2017/12/22 17:53</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.355048,lng:-79.835499},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelE.png',
        content:'<h1>Rt. 148 East @ Hartman 2017/12/22 20:14</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.384877,lng:-79.824477},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelW.png',
        content:'<h1>Rt.30 West @ Warren Dr. 2017/12/22 20:22</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.384488,lng:-79.824129},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelE.png',
        content:'<h1>Rt. 30 East @ Warren Dr. 2017/12/22 21:29</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.355285,lng:-79.834959},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelW.png',
        content:'<h1>Rt. 148 West @ Hartman 2017/12/22 21:38</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.355048,lng:-79.835499},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelE.png',
        content:'<h1>Rt. 148 East @ Hartman 2017/12/22 21:46</h1>'
        },
        {
         coords:{lat:40.337385,lng:-79.809023},
        iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelS.png',
        content:'<h1>48 SOUTH @ LINCOLN WAY 2017/12/22 22:19</h1>'
        }
      ];

      // Loop through markers
      for(var i = 0;i < markers.length;i++){
        // Add marker
        addMarker(markers[i]);
      }

      // Add Marker Function
      function addMarker(props){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:props.coords,
          map:map,
          icon:props.iconImage
        });

        // Check for customicon
        if(props.iconImage){
          // Set icon image
          marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
        }

        // Check content
        if(props.content){
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:props.content
          });

          marker.addListener('click', function(){
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }     
    var request = { travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING  };
    if (i == 0) request.origin = props.coords;
        else if (i == markers.length - 1) request.destination = props.coords;
    else {
    if (props.coords) 
        request.waypoints({
        location:props.coords,
        stopover: true
        });
    } 

      }
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=JAVASCRIPTAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code where you tried to use waypoints?

Comment: The route from those points is all over the place, do you have any additional information? (like the direction the vehicle was traveling when detected by  the camera?)

Comment: var request = { travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING  };
     if (i == 0) request.origin = props.coords;
   else if (i == markers.length - 1) request.destination = props.coords;
  else {
    if (props.coords) 
     request.waypoints({
      location:props.coords,
      stopover: true
     });

Comment: The cameras are pointing in the direction of travel and you can sort of tell by the camera name.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to address comments (it is hard to read code in the comments).  The posted code (such as it is, it isn't complete), is close to what I am using, but waypoints is an array, you probably want multiple entries, currently your code just adds the last "waypoint" marker's coordinate (as an object, not an array).

Comment: Rodney Howard , you forgot to close the else (closing accolade)

Comment: I'm curious, how do you know what route a car took between two cameras? Unless there is no alternative route, you're surely doing little more than guessing? And if that is the case, Google would most likely plot the most direct or quickest route, not necessarily the *actual* route.

Comment: It does take a little common sense.  If the plate passed a camera moving east on hwy 148 and then 3 minutes later passed another camera 1.5 miles further east on hwy 148, then passed another camera 5 minutes later and 2.5 miles north of the 2nd camera on hwy 51.  That does not leave a lot of time to side track off the main route.  
The objective is to make it easy for your average beat cop to see the route that has been taken so far and help track down the location of the missing child.  I don't want them to have to do the math and plot the route.  I want them to see the map and know.

Comment: I may not have made it clear but the content: variable holds the camera location and direction it is facing and the date time the plate passed:
content:'<h1>LINCOLN WAY WEST @ 48 2017/12/22 17:49</h1>'

Answer (score 2):

With some help from my niece the javascript developer I was able to get it working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>My Google Map</title>
          <style>
            #map{
              height:500px;
              width:750px;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>My Google Map</h1>
          <div id="map"></div>
          <script>
            function initMap(){
              // Map options
              var options = {
                zoom:12,
                center:{lat:40.355048,lng:-79.835499}
              }

              // New map
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
              var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
              var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
              var request = {   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING, optimizeWaypoints: true, waypoints: []  };

              // Listen for click on map
              google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
                // Add marker
                addMarker({coords:event.latLng});
              });

              // Array of markers
              var markers = [
                {
                 coords:{lat:40.337385,lng:-79.809023},
                iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelS.png',
                content:'<h1>48 SOUTH @ LINCOLN WAY 2017/12/22 17:53</h1>'
                },
                {
                 coords:{lat:40.355048,lng:-79.835499},
                iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelE.png',
                content:'<h1>Rt. 148 East @ Hartman 2017/12/22 20:14</h1>'
                },
                {
                 coords:{lat:40.384877,lng:-79.824477},
                iconImage:'http://52.15.229.165/nconf/google_images/cctv-32YelW.png',
                content:'<h1>Rt.30 West @ Warren Dr. 2017/12/22 20:22</h1>'
                }
              ];

              // Loop through markers
              for(var i = 0;i < markers.length;i++){
                // Add marker
                addMarker(markers[i]);
              }

              // Add Marker Function
              function addMarker(props){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:props.coords,
                  map:map,
                  icon:props.iconImage
                });

                // Check for customicon
                if(props.iconImage){
                  // Set icon image
                  marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
                }

                // Check content
                if(props.content){
                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:props.content
                  });

                  marker.addListener('click', function(){
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
                }     
                if (i === 0) { 
                    request.origin = props.coords; 
                }
                else if (i === markers.length - 1) {
                    request.destination = props.coords;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (props.coords) {
                        request.waypoints.push({
                        location: props.coords,
                        stopover: true
                            })
                        }

                    }
                //End of Add Marker Function
                }
            directionsService.route(request,function(response,status){
                if (status == "OK"){
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
                }
            })
            }
          </script>
          <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCIZsk8SNPVQMm8Tu4TXieZT0xIqkMSECo&callback=initMap">
            </script>
            <h4>A - PLATE:KCJ1372, 48 SOUTH @ LINCOLN WAY, 2017/12/22 17:53</h4>
            <h4>B - PLATE:KCJ1372, Rt. 148 East @ Hartman, 2017/12/22 20:14</h4>
            <h4>C - PLATE:KCJ1372, Rt.30 West @ Warren Dr., 2017/12/22 20:22</h4>

        </body>
        </html>
```